# How to disable a createjs tween

Tags: javascript, createjs, tween

I'm trying to disable a tween from continuing. The clock is remove from the screen but the function still fires.

I tried to do this below but after my "timerlength" is up I still hear the audio.

```
 clockContainer.removeAllChildren();
 self.stage.removeChild(mytweentodisable);
```

Not sure how to refactor it to stop the function from continuing.

```
      mytweentodisable = createjs.Tween.get(clockHand, { loop: false }).to({ rotation: 360 }, TimerLength).call(function () {
                //this will trigger the timer is up
                if (gameIsRunning == true) {
                    createjs.Sound.stop();
                    gameIsRunning = false;
                    createjs.Sound.play("gameOver");

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully I understood you goal :]

Removing tweens from an object is quite simple, and is done by calling:

`Tween.removeTweens(target)`

As described in TweenJS docs:

> removeTweens ( target )
>
> > Defined in removeTweens:444 Removes all
> >     existing tweens for a target. This is called automatically by new
> >     tweens if the override property is true. Parameters:
>
> target [Object]
>
> > The target object to remove existing tweens from.

Reference: http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html#method_removeTweens

You can see a very simple example Iv'e setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/2ot8pr0h/2/

(Clicking on the button will remove the tweens from all balls).

Comment: ok so i tried ....removeTweens(mytweentodisable) ... mytweentodisable.removeTweens(mytweentodisable) ... Tween.removeTweens(mytweentodisable) --- all of them tossed an error message.

Comment: Got it with this createjs.Tween.removeTweens(mytweentodisable);

Comment: What if you removed the element itself? For example, with `target.remove()`? Would the associated tweens also be removed?